# Directly substitute or match and substitute in perl

Tags: perl

Have a file with milions++ lines. Some lines are in the form of

```
123456_654321_some-random-text ( e.g. /\d{6}_\d{6}_(.*)/ )
```

others are simply

```
some-random-text
```

and others are different again...

What is the fastest way to remove the first 14 chars from my first example?

```
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    s/^\d{6}_\d{6}_//;  # so simple trying to substitute from every line
                        # and substitute will fail anyway when doesn't match
}
```

or

```
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    s/^.{14}// if m/^\d{6}_\d{6}_/;  # with condition...
}
```

it doesn't matter in a terms of speed (and correctness)...

Comment: Check out the [`Benchmark`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark) module and see for yourself.

Comment: @mob maybe someone other will have the same question - but ok - this is an answer too...

Comment: I would expect the first form, omitting the `if` clause, to run faster -- but, of course, there's no way to be certain without benchmarking.

Comment: Note that the second one would probably be faster than it currently is if you used substr instead of another regex.

Comment: Why are you concerned about speed?  Are you going to have to run this program over and over?  I suspect that any difference in string manipulation methods will be dwarfed by the disk I/O of reading in the millions+ lines of text, so it won't matter which technique you use.

Comment: what Andy Lester said.  but to actually answer your question, we would need to know what proportion of lines need the substitution?

Comment: @AndyLester, it sucks to process millions of lines.  He would like it to suck less.  He cannot make it suck less by reducing the millions of lines.  Pretty straightforward reason to desire 'micro' optimization of constant factors - those are the only factors he can possibly optimize.  And yeah, he's going to run it more than once: that's why he's here, asking, instead of already on to some other issue.  You're just telling him to get off your lawn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is mostly irrelevant what you use. You can run this benchmark:

```
$ perl <<'END'
use strict;
use warnings;
use Benchmark qw ( :all );

my @str = ('123456_654321_some-random-text' x 100, 'some text' x 50);

cmpthese( 3_000_000, {
     'regex'  => sub { map s/^\d{6}_\d{6}_//,                 @str; },
     'regex1' => sub { map /^\d{6}_\d{6}_/ && s/^.{14}//,     @str; },
     'split'  => sub { map /^\d{6}_\d{6}_/ && (split /_/)[2], @str; },
     'substr' => sub { map /^\d{6}_\d{6}_/ && substr($_, 14), @str; },
});
END
```

For me, this produces inconclusive results for such a small number of iterations. The result also varies depending on the phase of the moon and the ratio of matching to non-matching lines (here: `2:1`, but could also be `1:3`).

Generally, I'd prefer `s/^\d{6}_\d{6}_//`, as this leads to least duplication of work, and is the most clear thing to read.

On running a longer benchmark with

```
my @str = ('123456_654321_some-random-text' x 100, 'some text' x 50)x100;
```

I got the following results:

```
          Rate  split regex1 substr  regex
split  39139/s     --   -12%   -14%   -18%
regex1 44603/s    14%     --    -2%    -7%
substr 45338/s    16%     2%     --    -5%
regex  47740/s    22%     7%     5%     --
```

which prefers this simple substitution. But `substr` isn't far behind either. However, these benchmarks are quite artificial: there is only one matching and one non-matching string, which occur in continuous sequences of 50–100 strings. This does not model actual data, which is far more random.

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove the first fourteen characters?

I bet that [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) will be faster than regex matches.

As Perl programmers, we are so tuned into regular expressions, we sometimes forget the non-regex ways of doing things, and these are usually faster.

Use the

```
while( my $line = <> ) {
    chomp $line;
    $line = substr($line, 14);
}
```

Use the [Benchmark](http://perldoc.perl.org/Benchmark.html) module and see.

Comment: He only wants to remove the first 14 characters in his first example, but not the second.  Regexes are going to be required here.